# Examples of preadditive categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

The obvious examples for preadditive categories / $\textsf{Ab}$-enriched categories are of course:

- $R$-$\textsf{Mod}$, the category of $R$-modules for any ring $R$
- $\textsf{Ab}$, the category of abelian groups
- $R$-$\textsf{Mat}$, the category of natural numbers with $R$-matrices as morphisms
- any ring $R$
- <s>Mod, the category of multi-sorted modules (I think)</s> (I haven't tried to check this, but according to Zhen Lin $\mathsf{Mod}$ is not preadditive)

Are there any other good examples of preadditive categories?

Comment: "up to possibly one or two small lies": well, up to a fairly large lie, I think! :-)

Comment: @JeremyRickard I meant: With composition defined as matrix multiplication and assuming the axiom of choice we have an equivalence of categories $R$-$\mathsf{Mod} \simeq R$-$\mathsf{Mat}^{\text{op}}$. If you define matrix multiplication in reversed order (which is consistent with writing $fg$ instead of $g\circ f$) one lie disappers. The need for the axiom of choice disappears in homotopy type theory for example, or so I heard. EDIT: actually nevermind, I think I'm thinking of rings that are at least commutative or maybe even fields.

Comment: The total category of modules is not preadditive.

Comment: An important example is category of presheaves $[\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}},\mathcal A]$ for any category $\mathcal C$ and any preadditive category $\mathcal A$. Addition is defined pointwise.

Comment: @Ennar Are there any especially important (perhaps named) special cases of this construction?

Comment: Sure, one can define $\mathcal A$-valued sheaves as a full subcategory of $[\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}},\mathcal A]$, which is then preadditive by fullness. See for example [sheaf of modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_of_modules).